# How to get StateContext in StateMachineListener and how to config states to implement my statechart?

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

My First Question:

In my `StateMachineConfiguration.class`.

```
@Bean
public StateMachineListener<CompanyStatus, CompanyEvents> listener() {
    return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<CompanyStatus, CompanyEvents>() {
        @Override
        public void transition(Transition<CompanyStatus, CompanyEvents> transition) {
            if(transition.getTarget().getId() == CompanyStatus.COMPANY_CREATED) {
                logger.info("公司创建，发送消息到用户服务和菜单服务");
                // how to get stateContext in there?
                StateContext stateContext;
                Message message = new Message.Builder<String>().messageType(CompanyStatus.COMPANY_CREATED.toString()).build();
                messageSender.sendToUaa(message);
                messageSender.sendToRes(message);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

In my service.

```
log.debug("Request to save Company : {}", companyDTO);
    Company company = companyMapper.toCmpy(companyDTO);
    company = companyRepository.save(company);
    stateMachine.sendEvent(MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(CompanyEvents.COMPANY_CREATE)
        .setHeader("companyId", company.getId())
        .build());
    return companyMapper.toCmpyDTO(company);
```

How I can get message header[companyId] in listener?

My Second Question:
[statechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBIon.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `StateMachineListener` you could use its `stateContext` method which gives you access to `StateContext`. `StateContext` then have access to message headers via its `getMessageHeaders`.

Original listener interface didn't expose that much so we had to add new method which exposes context which were introduced to machine later than listener interface were created. This because we need not to break things and we generally like to be backward compatibility.